# Synchronizing LinkedHashmap externally

Tags: java, concurrency

What is the best way to implement synchronization of a linkedhashmap externally, without using Collections.synchronizedMap

When Collections.synchronizedMap is used entire datastructure is locked, so performance is hugely impacted in a bad way.

What is the best way to lock only required part of datastructure. e.g. If thread is accessing key (K1), it should lock only Key(K1) and Value(v1) part of the datastructure

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement that it be a *linked* map?

Comment: Yea, I am loooking for a hashmap with a efficient FIFO eviction policy. Linkedhashmap is the only datastructure I could think of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a fine-grained-locking, FIFO-eviction concurrent map from the built-in Java implementations.

Check out [Guava's `Cache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) or the open-source [`ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` project](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to synchronize the subsequent operation you do, just on the value coming from the map:

```
Object value = map.get(key);
synchronized(value) {
    doSomethingWith(value);
}
```

Synchronizing to values get from the Map, makes sense, since they can be shared and accessed concurrently; the example I posted above should do what you need. That should be enough.

By the way you can also synchronize on the key doing two nested synchronized blocks:

```
synchronized(key) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    synchronized(value) {
        doSomethingWith(value);
    } 
}
```

The key is -usually- just used to access the object (by hashing). Keys are matched by hash value, so it doesn't make full sense to me to synchronize over the key.

Or, maybe you can subclass `ConcurrentHashMap` adding what is missing from `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Louis Wasserman's suggestion is probably the best because it gives you a lot of useful functionality. However, even if you lock on the entire map, you have to be hitting it really, really hard to make that a bottleneck (as in, your code is mostly doing read/write on the map). If you don't need the additional functionality of Guava's `Cache`, a synchronized map could be simpler & better. You could also use a `ReadWriteLock` if you mostly read from the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a `LinkedHaspMap`, use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) from the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

It is specifically designed for both speed and thread safety. It uses the minimal possible locking to achieve its thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` .

I can't see how it would be possible to externally lock only parts of zour Map, since you cannot control what shared datastructures are accessed internally by a call to any of the maps function.

Answer (score 0):

An insertion in a HashMap, or LinkedHashMap, can cause a rehash because it increases the ratio between the size and the number of buckets. Having two or more threads rehash simultaneously would be a disaster.

Even if you are only doing a get, another thread may be removing an entry from the same bucket, so you are scanning a linked list that is being modified under you. You could also have two or more threads appending to the main linked list at the same time.

If you can do without the linking, use java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap, as already suggested.

Comment: I need linking (atleast thats what I think) because I am looking for an implementation of a hashmap with fifo eviction policy. It shouldn't rehash (or increase the capacity), but it should evict on a FIFO policy

Comment: If you only need a FIFO, you could create your own class that wraps around ConcurrentHashMap that maintains a FIFO. Of course, you will need to be careful to make sure your FIFO is itself a concurrent data structure and consistent with your hash map.